# Eclipse: How to set the main method for a project?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, when you create a new class, you can select the option 
"Which methods stubs would like to create:" and you can choose " **public static void main(String args[])**".

I have created a class with a main method, but I haven't checked that option and I receive this error: "**selection does not contain a main type in eclipse**".
How can I show Eclipse that I have a main method in the class, without deleting/recreating the class file?

Later Edit: 
:) My mistake: 
My main method looks like this: **public static void main(String args)** and because of this, I received the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the signature of your method is wrong. It has to be *exactly:*

```
public static void main(String[])
```

otherwise it won't work. Naming the method `Main` will fail, omitting the argument to the method will fail. Also, I think the class needs to be public.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have a method of the type
`public static void main(String[] args)`
?

You should check if you have no typos in your code. Maybe you could post an example of your main-method's head.

Answer (score 0):

One shortcut that really helps me, Eclipse has syntax suggestions, and if you type "main" into the terminal window and hit control + space, you can choose main method and it'll populate it complete with enclosed braces. Helpful if you're not always quick to remember syntax off the top of your head!